# How can I add a new row in a table every 10 rows, automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I have a table getting data from a model with a `foreach`, in a razor view.. I want to add a new row every 10 rows, how can I do that?

**EDIT**

```
    <tbody>

    @foreach (var context in sortedData)
    {

        @for (int i = 1; i % 10 == 0;i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    new row

                </td>
            </tr>
            
        }
        <tr>
            <td>
                @context.Id
            </td>
            <td>@context.CantidadElegida</td>
            <td>@context.Item</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.Price)</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.Reposition)</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.SubTotal)</td>

        </tr>

    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: set `int count = 1;` outside the loop, then in the loop, after entering a row, `if (count++ % 10 == 0)`, insert a new row.

Comment: I’m doing it with a `for` within the `foreach`, but it’s not working. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Why don't you show your code, then we can see what to do.

Comment: I shared it now

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop inside the `foreach` loop; that won't work (especially written with a condition like that - it will never add a new row). You need to increment `i` only after you add a new row, like I mentioned in the first comment. `int i = 0; foreach (var context in sortedData) { // add context row info; if (i++ % 10 == 0) { // add new row; } }`

Comment: Now it's working bro, thanks for your support! you can post your answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
int count=1;
 @foreach (var context in sortedData)
    {

        if ( count++ % 10 == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    new row

                </td>
            </tr>
            
        }
        <tr>
            <td>
                @context.Id
            </td>
            <td>@context.CantidadElegida</td>
            <td>@context.Item</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.Price)</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.Reposition)</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.SubTotal)</td>

        </tr>


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for this.

```
int count=1;
 @foreach (var context in sortedData)
    {

        if ( count % 10 == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    new row

                </td>
            </tr>
            
        }
        <tr>
            <td>
                @context.Id
            </td>
            <td>@context.CantidadElegida</td>
            <td>@context.Item</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.Price)</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.Reposition)</td>
            <td>@String.Format("RD${0:f2}", @context.SubTotal)</td>

        </tr>

count++;
    }
```